# C# Strong Naming of dll, not detecting modifications

Tags: c#, corruption, strongname

It is my understanding that strong naming creates a cryptographic Hash of the a assembly to which is used as a strong name to load the dll.

I was hoping to use this feature to detect corruption of a binary to inform the user there is a problem with the software and they need to reinstall it.

This works for some changes to the binary, however i've found modifying the binary, especially static strings within the binary, does not cause the application to report that it cannot locate a dll of the appropriate strong name.

Can anyone explain to me what data from an assembly is used to create the strong name, and why strong naming does not always detect the modification of the dll? Is there a way that i can force it to include additional information in the strong naming?

Is there a alternate way i can detect a corruption of a binary?

Cheers

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look here: [Authenticode Signatures and Strong Name Signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/shawnfa/authenticode-and-assemblies) and [How do I Sign .Net assemblies with Authenticode signature?](https://www.guidanceshare.com/wiki/How_do_I_Sign_.Net_assemblies_with_Authenticode_signature%3F)

> These two signatures are completely independent of each other.  A strong name helps to provide a unique identity for an assembly. Authenticode allows you to verify who the author of the assembly is.

And

> If both types of signatures are applied to an assembly, the strong name signature is wrapped within the Authenticode signature.  Meaning that I could modify the bytes of the Authenticode signature so that it is no longer valid without invalidating the strong name signature.  The reverse is not true -- modifying the bytes of the strong name signature would invalidate both it and the Authenticode signature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Authenticode is about signing your assembly to indicate the author is who they say they are and that the software can be trusted. 

My concern is not about trusting the source, as this software is for internal use only. 

My concern is that the software is to be used in a critical process so we want to know if the binary has become corrupted so we can inform the operator that it needs to be re-installed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the hash used in strong-naming includes the entire file, so I am not sure why some changes are not tripping the verification.

Is there any chance your assembly is added in skip-verification list?

Comment: No, Some changes seem to trip the strong naming while others don't. Specifically if i modify the content of statically compiled data like constants or strings, i get no warning about not being able to locate a dll with the correct strong name and the application executes without complaint but the output is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The digital signature created when strong naming an assembly hashes the contents of the assembly, with the **exception** of any Authenticode Signature, the assembly's strong name data, and the PE header checksum, then signs the hash with the private key.

Perhaps it was one of the excluded items that you were changing, in which case the strong name will still verify correctly and the assembly will still load just fine.

A strong name by definition consists of four attributes: a file name (minus extension), a version number, a culture identity, and a public key token (a hash of the public key). There is no way to include additional information in the strong naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

I detected the same behaviour. I strong named the assemblies then I modified some static strings with an hex editor. Suprisingly, the executable that is loading the assembly did not throw any exception but just loaded the altered library.
After some searching in Microsoft docs I found a hint that helped me.

It is saying that there is a bypass mechanism that shall load the assemblies faster when some conditions are true.

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/assembly/create-use-strong-named#bypass-signature-verification-of-trusted-assemblies

To disable this bypassing you have put a flag in the app.config.

```
<runtime>
   <bypassTrustedAppStrongNames enabled="false" />
</runtime>
```

After doing that the executable is throwing an exception when the assembly was modified.

[image]